# Angular5 Material -> Close mat-expansion-panel when switch TAB

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have an Angular Material tabs component. When I switch the Tab the Mat-expansion-panel are already open in the new Tab. So my click on the panel-header not work to refresh my Data. How can i close the expansion Panel when i switch the Tab?

```
<mat-tab label="Edelstahl">
              <div class="tab-content visible-sm-12">
                <mat-accordion>
                  <mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="true">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                      <div class="row_accordion disabled">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">Typ</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-4 text-right">Euro / kg</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1  text-right">Euro / m²</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  </mat-expansion-panel>
                  <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="getArticelTyp(4945)">
                      <div class="row_accordion">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">12NE</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-4 text-right"> 9,10</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1 text-right">89,29</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5269) in Angular Material 2. There's a pending fix as of `6.0.0-beta.0`.

Comment: Hello
I have added the 6.0.0-beta.4 and it works perfect, but I need one more Help. When I expand the Mat-expand panel the I see the Content. I scroll down and click the next one Mat-expansion-panel-header I would do ahead to the first entry. But it is in the same position I click the header. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is it possible to use angular material 6 with angular 5.2.0 ?

Comment: Per the project's ['package.json'](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/package.json), it appears it is dependent on Angular `6.0.0-rc.1`.